# How can i rename the bulk testcases in testplan in HP Quality Centre?

Tags: quality-center, hp-quality-center

Using HP Quality Centre, how can I rename test cases in bulk, within a test plan.

Answer (score 1):

Change the view to Test Grid (View > Test Grid) that will add the Replace command in the Edit menù.

[image]

In the Replace popup select Test Name in `Find in Field`, put the current value in `Value to Find` and the new value in `Replace with`.

[image]

By default partial match is enable, ie.: if you have a test with the test name **foo**_test_1, put **foo** in `Value to Find` and **bar** in `Replace with` and hit `Replace` the new test name will be **bar**_test_1

**Note:** the screenshot are taken from HP ALM 11.52, the functionality is present also in HP QC, at least from version 10.00.
[Online help page](http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/Latest/online_help/Content/UG/ui_replace.htm) of HP ALM 12.50 for Replace.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added which version of QC/ALM you are using in your example.

Comment: @JohnOglesby I added a note at the bottom of the answer